# Python requests library POST request not working

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm attempting to login & scrape a website which obfuscates the URL.

The first step is to login on the site's login page, which I've successfully done using Python's `requests` package.

The second step is to input some data into this below form and "click" Search, as displayed in the below picture. This is where I'm having difficulties.

[image]

If I do this through my browser, it'll take about 30 seconds to load, there will be a fancy graphic corresponding to the loading screen, then the full page with text will load up (this is what I wish to scrape).

When I inspect the source of the form input box from inside my browser, I see this:

```html
<form id="companysearch_form" method="post" style="display: inline;">
   <input name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" type="hidden" value="bTo9V2w4tcHsgKkIucS9c0Nkzv5rhueqEjOdQLexg3pWqApZ9Ht4xYboj6y9TIwy"/>
   <div class="form-group" id="div_id_company_symbols"> 
   <div class=""> <input class="textinput textInput form-control" id="id_company_symbols" maxlength="100" name="company_symbols" placeholder="Symbols..." required="" type="text"/> 
   </div> 
   </div> 
   <input id="id_honeypot" name="honeypot" type="hidden"/>
   <button class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

This is my attempt:

```py
import sys
import requests

login_URL = '' # this is the landing page URL where I have to login
companysearch_URL = '' # this is where I get directed to automatically after I login

client = requests.session()

def get_csrftoken(client):
    if 'csrftoken' in client.cookies:
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
    else:
        csrftoken = client.cookies['csrf']
    return csrftoken


## STEP 1 - this works brilliantly ##
client.get(login_URL)
token = get_csrftoken(client)

payload = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : token, 
    'login':'username', 
    'password':'password'
}

s = client.post(login_URL, data=payload)


## STEP 2 ATTEMPT - this doesn't work. ##
payload = {
    'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : token, 
    'company_symbols':'NVDA'
}

s = client.post(companysearch_URL, data=payload)
```

When I run stage 2, the `s = client.post(companysearch_URL, data=payload)` will run in one second, so I immediately know it didn't work. I then read the text of `s` and notice that there is no data at all.

Headers from `s`:

```
{'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Date': 'Thu, 17 Dec 2020 20:27:48 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache/2.4.46 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.12', 'Set-Cookie': 'csrftoken=K01sxNa1M1st9BlpwAdlyEu1VIudSek9PCGhZViozNiqbROnC62YuzHzExoRVAZM; expires=Thu, 16 Dec 2021 20:27:48 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax; Secure', 'Vary': 'Cookie,X-Forwarded-Proto', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Frame-Options': 'DENY', 'Content-Length': '12298', 'Connection': 'keep-alive'}
```

Comment: It sounds like that site uses javascript.  The `requests` python module cannot do javascript.

Comment: @JohnGordon It does, what library should I use then? Thank you

Comment: Check out `selenium`.

Comment: @ABC See [Web-scraping JavaScript page with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8049520/web-scraping-javascript-page-with-python)